# How can I "log out" using httpclient in Android?

Tags: java, android, html, httpclient

the thing is that I use HttpClient(I know is deprecated) to log in into a webpage, I use httpost to log in and httpget to download some pages, this works perfectly.

But after this finishes, the session get lost and if I try to login using their web page, "you have logged in using another device, please wait until the session expires"(one hour), this is the same as if I use the browser to login and then delete the cookie manually(I did it myself).

So I logged in and decided to inspect the html code and found this code from the logout button on the web page:

```
<a href="https://webpage.com/index/logout">
<i class="fa fa-power-off">
</i>
</a>
```

Notice that I changed to webpage name but kept the /index/logout

so I opened another tab and paste the link,"https://webpage.com/index/logout" enter, and I was logged out normally.

so I was thinking, is there a way to do this with HttpClient? 
I tried using a httpget and not worked.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "not worked"? Make a GET request to that URL with the session cookie and it should work.

Comment: Man, I can't believe it, I tried again and it worked flawlessly, can't believe it was that easy, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using a HttpGet to the logout page did all the work, it was simple as that.
Don't forget to use the HttpGet with the HttpContext that you used to log in.